# Odata Syntax to Orderby a Lookup Column Result

Tags: rest, odata

I have need to order an Odata call by by the results of a lookup list.  I am having trouble using the $expand operator in tandem with the orderby operator.  What changes can I make so that my Odata results reflect these needs?

currently I have

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('myList')/items?$filter=Field1 eq 'Yes'&$orderby=Field1,lookupCol/results asc&?$expand=lookupCol
```

lookupCol needs to be one of the **orderby** columns, but I cannot manage to make that work, I am being told that:

> The field 'lookupCol' of type 'LookupMulti' cannot be used in the query sort expression.

Comment: try using $orderby=Field1 asc or $orderby=lookupCol/results asc instead of $orderby=Field1,lookupCol/results asc

Comment: same here, I can't find a way to "orderby" any Rest query using a lookup with "expand" :(